# Codelite compiling issues (mingw32-make.exe *** [ALL] Error 2)

Tags: codelite

I'm having serious issues with Codelight. It has been working for days now, maybe even weeks but after today when I took my project to school to work on it there something happened. My workspace is in a onedrive folder so that I can work on it wherever I am. I have reinstalled codelight and reinstalled MinGW and set it up according to my school's instructions but right now I can't build anything at all (see attached image). I have been looking at other threads but none of them have helped so far. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvAys.png)

What do you think happened?

Edit: I seem to have fixed the issue. When you let codelite search for a compiler, as it does the first time you launch it, you mess up the directories of things completely. So for example the directory for the C compiler should be $(CodeLiteDir)/tools/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe instead of C:\MinGW or wherever it may be installed. Also, we use a patched version of codelite with 'added debugging support' for the md407 so you really don't want to update codelite. There were more issues, for example the C compiler options for my project, so when I built the project it complained about all sorts of things and the cursor wouldn't show up so debugging was impossible, but I managed to fix that too.

In conclusion: this was not fun to fix and codelite is sensitive.

Comment: Find out what changed today / overnight / since you last run/compiled it successfully ! This could very well be due to some environmental change !

Comment: Did you install a different gcc? Is your project supposed to use a cross compiler?

Comment: @melpomene I completely forgot to mention this but I did a fresh install of windows and had to download Codelite again. But still, I followed the instructions like I did the first time I got it so what could have changed?  I'm not sure if  we are supposed to use a cross compiler. I just tried making a hello world app but it doesn't work with MinGW or Cross GCC.

Comment: Actually yes we are supposed to use a cross compiler. The point of the project is to program a board called md407

Comment: Okay so if I make a simple executable hello world application using Cross GCC and GNU gdb as debugger, that works. When I build this project a main.c.o-file is created inside the Debug folder, however, this does not happen when I use the user-template that I am supposed to use when programming the md407. So right now I'm getting an error saying something about a recipe for the target 'Debug/startup.c.o'.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dev-C++ I got similiar 'Mingw32-make.exe' errors. When installing Mingw you will notice there is another directory **'c:\Mingw32\MSYS\1.0\bin'**. Within MSYS this directory is global and it has some very important binary files like its own 'make.exe' file. 'Mingw32-make.exe' uses files from this directory. Because the IDE will not know about this directory you will need to include this in your system/environment path because outside of MSYS this directory is not global and 'ming32-make.exe' will not be able to access those binary files.

Regardless of your compiler if your 'make' is Mingw32 that path must be set.