# mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2 - Codelite

Tags: c++, codelite

I'm new to codelite and I've just installed it. During the installation I let codelite search for a compiler on my PC(win10 64bit). Did it mess up the directories of things as I've read in another question?! Well, if that's the case I've no idea how to fix this problem.
Can someone help me?
Cheers

Comment: What problem? What other question? Please be more specific. [Ask] will give you good understanding of what is required for a good question. It sounds more like your compilation failed.

Comment: when I tried building my first program (hello world) the error "mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2" showed up. I was referring to the question with the same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988411/codelite-compiling-issues-mingw32-make-exe-all-error-2